# String array to Int array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to get a string from the console and put all elements in an int array.
It throws an error that my input was in a wrong format. I am trying with "1 1 3 1 2 2 0 0" and I need those as int values and later perform some calculations with them.

Here is my attempt:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {

    string first = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] First = new string[first.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        First[i] += first[i];
    }

    int[] Arr = new int[First.Length];//int array for string console values
    for (int i = 0; i < First.Length; i++)//goes true all elements and converts them into Int32
    {
        Arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(First[i].ToString());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++)//print array to see what happened
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Arr[i]);
    } 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
       string numberStr = Console.ReadLine(); // "1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 ...."
       string[] splitted = numberStr.Split(' ');
       int[] nums = new int[splitted.Length];

       for(int i = 0 ; i < splitted.Length ; i++)
       {
         nums[i] = int.Parse(splitted[i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

try this

```
string str = "1 1 3 1 2 2 0 0";
int[] array = str.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

[Demo](http://dotnetfiddle.net/AEsHxi)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method to split your string with space`' '` in an array of strings and then convert each element to integer. You can iterate string array using [System.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in efficient manner

```
using System.Linq; //You need add reference to namespace

static void Main()
{
    string numbersStr = "1 1 3 1 2 2 0 0";
    int[] numbersArrary = numbersStr.Split(' ').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/brtGO0)

Answer (score 2):

You are not splitting the string using space delimiter.

```
        string first = Console.ReadLine();
        int len = first.Split(new []
                         {' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        string[] First = new string[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            First[i] = first.Split(' ')[i];
        }

        int[] Arr = new int[First.Length];//int array for string console values
        for (int i = 0; i < First.Length; i++)//goes true all elements and converts them into Int32
        {
            Arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(First[i].ToString());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++)//print array to see what happened
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Arr[i]);
        }
```

Comment: This is the only answer that handles multiple spaces between numbers. GFG did this to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
string[] arr = s.Split(' '); //Split the single string into multiple strings using space as delimiter
int[] intarr = new int[arr.Length];

for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
 {
  intarr[i] = int.Parse(arr[i]); //Parse the string as integers and fill the integer array
 }

for(int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
 {
  Console.Write(intarr[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant try with "1 1 3 1 2 2 0 0", because it is trying to parse the spaces between the numbers. If you want your program to work you have to either make your input string like that: "11312200" or you can make a char array or just a single char if you dont have more than one separator where you assign and then .split the string by passing the separator, like that:

```
string Numbers = "1 1 3 1";

string[] seperatedNumbers = Numbers.Split(' ');

// perform your following actions
```

Comment: You should assign to a `String[]` variable in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple extension method:

Using:

```
 var stringArray = "0,1,2,3,4,5";
 stringArray.ParseIntArray();
```

Code:

```
//separator parameter: default value is ',' you can use whatever you want. ' ', '|', ';'

public static int[] ParseIntArray(this string source, char separator = ',')
{
   return Array.ConvertAll(source.Split(separator), int.Parse);
}
```

If you don't want to get an exception you can use this.
It returns `new int[] {0}` when throw an exception.

Using:

```
var stringArray = "0,1,2,3,4,5";
stringArray.TryParseIntArray();
```

Code:

```
public static int[] TryParseIntArray(this string source, char separator = ',')
{
   int[] arrInt;

   try
     {
       arrInt = Array.ConvertAll(source.Split(separator), int.Parse);          
     }
   catch (Exception ex)
     {
       arrInt = new int[] { 0 };
     }

  return arrInt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer - BTW surely it would be better to return an *empty* array as the general best choice when there's an exception?